# Solr 4 is there a real need to increase MaxPermSize

Tags: solr

Trying to see where Solr memory issue is coming from, and garbage collection is obvious candidate. I see examples googling where -XX:MaxPermSize is set to either 128MB, 256 MB or more. Does Solr dynamically generate and load classes? That is, why should MaxPermSize be adjusted if it does not grow? Also, should Solr log show Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error if memory problem is due to PermGenSize?

Note that I am using Java 7 and JBoss.

Thanks,
Ona

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is modify the file `bin\standalone.conf` and add the following line:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m "
```

Then restart jboss.

Comment: I know but my real question is if why use 256m as opposed to 128m. Another question is if containers share same PermGen space for all applications as PermGen space is part of JVM.